# Delayed choice quantum eraser setup with no beam splitter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-eraser

I know this question has probably been discussed many times before. But, I need a clear answer about this setup, in case there is no [beam splitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_splitter).

[image: delayed choice setup]

What is going to happen in this situation? My classical intuition, says I will see a correlated interference pattern on both screens (or detectors), but in reality I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this question in another physics forum. The answer is we don't get interference pattern or any other pattern at all. In this setup, photons coming from slits are uncorrelated and because of that we will only see a line on the dedectors.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQXQF.png) Kim, Y.-H., Yu, R., Kulik, S. P. and Shih, Y. Delayed “choice” quantum eraser. Phys. Rev. Lett. 84, 1-5 (2000).

Comment: In the setup you are getting 2 overlapping patterns .... that is why it's not visible.  But technically the photons are interfering with the 2 slits.  Adding BS gives the EM field of the atom ( the excited atom about to create the photon) a chance at creating the photon thru one slit only instead of 2.   The EM field is very active before after during photon creation.

Comment: I should have said "after crystal" not "after slits" sorry for that